# List elements as function arguments Scala

Tags: scala

I have a function that takes 5 parameters:

```
MyFunction(arg1: String, arg2: String, ..., arg5: String)
```

And a List that has 4 Items

```
List("a","b","c","d")
```

I want to simply know how to pass the elements of the list as the 4 first parametres of the function in Scala

Comment: Use pattern matching.

Comment: not really the case where I need pattern matching

Comment: how can you pass 4 parameters if your method takes 5 ? What do you pass to the last one ? It's a default parameter ?

Comment: @IhebMarnaoui *"not really the case where I need pattern matching"* Well, 5 string arguments, a tuple of 5 strings, and a list of 5 strings (and a list of 5 strings when 5 is known statically) are different things. Static typing being useful to prevent errors is not actually for free.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to use pattern matching (as **@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez** proposed in comments)

```
def myFunction(arg1: String, arg2: String, arg3: String, arg4: String, arg5: String): String = 
  arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4 + arg5

val args = List("a","b","c","d")

val List(a, b, c, d) = args // <-- pattern matching
myFunction(a, b, c, d, "e") // abcde
```

More exotic way is

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.function._
import shapeless.syntax.std.traversable._

(myFunction _).toProduct((args :+ "e").toSizedHList(5).get) // abcde
```